# Does Laravel redirect affect bounce rate?

Tags: redirect, laravel, seo, bounce

I'm using this statement to redirect the landing page to another page.

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function() {
  Redirect::to('/'.$lang.'/someotherpage');
}
```

Google Analytics states Bounce Rate as below:

> Bounce Rate is the percentage of single-page visits (i.e. visits in
>   which the person left your site from the entrance page without
>   interacting with the page).

So will using the redirect on my landing page affect the bounce rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it shouldn't affect the bounce rate. `Redirect::to()` generates a 302 redirect response and the browser reacts directly to it. Google Analytics is **JavaScript based** and will never run and therefore not see or track the redirect.

This might be different for JavaScript redirects. Although I don't know that for sure.